# reply to udp packet is blocked

Tags: c, udp, firewall

I am writing a C program to search for smb shares on the local network and mount them.
to get the hostnames of the smb servers found I send an udp nbns packet to the server.
The packet is correct and the server replies.
I am using wireshark to check this.
I compared the packet I sent with a packet send by nbstat and I also compared the packets returned by the server.
exept for the id and the checksum they are identical.

when I do the request using nbstat the reply packet is received proper, but the reply to my own packet is probably blocked by the firewall.
After receiving the reply from the server the client machine sends an icmp "Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)" message to the server.
I suspect my firewall sending it.

this is the output from wireshark

No. Time      Source        Destination   Protocol Length Info
12  29.870065 192.168.1.245 192.168.1.21  NBNS     92     Name query NBSTAT *<00><00.......
13  29.870494 192.168.1.21  192.168.1.245 NBNS     253    Name query response NBSTAT
14  29.870559 192.168.1.245 192.168.1.21  ICMP     281    Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)

What should I do to allow the reply to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your program listening on UDP port 137 to receive server reply?
If not that explains why your host sends ICMP packet Port Unreachable.

If you listening on port 137, try to configure source port when you are sending NBNS query to be port 137. So the firewall will now that it should let packets to this port.

Comment: I accidently pointed bind to the wrong sockaddr structure. I bound it to port 137 on the server ip. Changing it to the right sockaddr instance made the ICMP message disappear. I guess my problem is solved.

Comment: Things can be so easy when you finally understand. My last comment is not correct. I assumed that my program should listen on port 137 and to achieve this I made two instances of struct sockaddr_in one with the server ip and port 137 and one with the client ip and port 137. I used the first for the socket and the second for bind. this was the mistake. I now use the first for both socket and bind. That solved the problem.